# Are there better ways to do Map k [v] -> Maybe (Map k v)?

Tags: haskell

I want to create a function that turns `Map k [v]` ([Data.Map.Strict](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html)) into `Maybe (Map k v)`.

What it does is this:

- If any of the lists doesn't have exactly one element, the function returns `Nothing`.
- If all of the lists have exactly one element, it returns the expected map wrapped in a `Just`.

The only thing I can think of is to do this manually with `foldrWithKey'` or `foldlWithKey'`. Are there better ways?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking for `traverse :: (Traverseable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)` from [`Data.Traversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html) (but also in the Prelude).

```
justOne :: [a] -> Maybe a
justOne [x] = Just x
justOne _ = Nothing

allJustOne :: Map k [v] -> Maybe (Map k v)
allJustOne = traverse justOne
```

`traverse f` is probably best understood as `sequenceA . fmap f`. `sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)` on the other hand is a way of pulling the applicative "effects" out of a `Traversable` structure. For example one might execute a list of `IO` actions with `sequenceA :: [IO a] -> IO [a]`. Or in the case of `Maybe` the result will be `Just` if all the elements in the `Traversable` structure are `Just` and if any of the elements is `Nothing` the result of `sequenceA` will also be `Nothing`.

If you know `sequence` or `mapM`, `sequenceA` and `traverse` are just generalisations of those.

Comment: Note that you can generalize the function `justOne` quite a bit: `foldr (\a _ -> pure a) empty :: (Alternative f, Foldable t) => t a -> f a`, which intuitively produces the right-most element or fails if the container is empty.

Comment: @user2407038, left-most.

Comment: @user2407038. Yes, the Foldable generalization is fine, however I'm not sure the `pure` generalisation is terribly useful. Does it do something useful and expected for any applicative for example (e.g. `ZipList` or `(->)`)? Related: https://wiki.haskell.org/Why_not_Pointed%3F

Comment: @jpath It's using `Alternative`, not `Applicative`.

Comment: https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-6.16/base-4.8.2.0/Data-Maybe.html#v:listToMaybe

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake `listToMaybe [1,2] = Just 1 ≠ Nothing = justOne [1,2]`

Comment: @jpath Oh yeah. True.